# How to run ps1 from power shell which contain ()in directory path

Tags: python, powershell

I’m trying to run ps1 files from python by using

```
import os
os.system('powershell -Command' + ' ' +'powershell -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned C:\hoge\test.ps1')
```

But the dir path is like under it won’t run.

```
'powershell -Command' + ' ' +'powershell -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned C:\hoge(foo)\test.ps1'
```

It looks like poweshell is only recognizing C:\hoge

Is there any way to run the ps1 in situations?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: To run a PowerShell file, you need to use the -file argument: `powershell -file C:\hoge(foo)\test.ps1`

Comment: Why are you launching powershell and then immediately asking it to launch another child process of powershell?

Answer (score 0):

- You only need *one* `powershell.exe` call, and since you're invoking a script *file* (`*.ps1`) use the `-File` [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) parameter.
- In `'...'` Python string literals, *verbatim* `\` characters must be escaped as `\\`
- If your `*.ps1` script's file path contains spaces or other PowerShell metacharacters such as `(` and `)`, it must be enclosed in `"..."` on the command line.

```
import os
os.system('powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -File "C:\\hoge(foo)\\test.ps1"')
```